# How to reduce the border width of sideBarPanel in Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, panel

I can't for the life of me find an argument or SO question regarding this, so I'm asking:

**How do you modify the size (width or height) of the gap border around a `sideBarPanel`?**

My best solution has been to play with border values via `div` for individual elements, but I'm wondering how to change the border around the whole thing?

The goal is to reduce the border gap so that I have "more room" for my elements when I zoom in (instead of them getting scrunched).

Here's sample code showing the "problem":

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(
    h1("NMS Comparing tool", style = "font-size: 15px")
  ),

  sidebarPanel(width = 3, 
               div(style = "font-size: 8px;", 
                   sliderInput(inputId = "groups", 
                               label = "No. of Groups",
                               value = 4, min = 2, max = 12)
               ),  

               fluidRow(
                 column(6,offset=0,
                        div(style = "height: 105px; padding: 0px 0px",  
                            plotOutput(outputId = "scree")
                        )
                 ),

                 column(6,offset=0,
                        div(style = "font-size: 8px;padding: 0px 48px 15px; height: 105px",  #padding is top, right, bottom, left??
                            checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "labels",
                                               label = "Labels",
                                               choices = c("SPEC","Plot-End","Plot-Start"),
                                               selected = c("SPEC","Plot-End","Plot-Start")
                            )    
                        )
                 )
               ),

               fluidRow(
                 column(6,offset=0,
                        div(style = "font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 0px",      
                            radioButtons(inputId = "data",
                                         label = "Data",
                                         choices = c("PSP Only","PSP + MAP"),
                                         selected = "PSP + MAP")
                        )    
                 ),

                 column(6,offset=0,
                        div(style = "font-size: 8px;padding: 0px 10px;",  
                            radioButtons(inputId = "freq",
                                         label = "Frequency",
                                         choices = c(0.025,0.05),
                                         selected = 0.05)
                        )
                 )
               ),

               fluidRow(
                 column(6,offset=0,
                        div(style = "font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 0px; ",                 
                            radioButtons(inputId = "arrows",
                                         label = "Vector Choice",
                                         choices = c("Cumulative Change","All Samples","Hurricane"),
                                         selected = "Cumulative Change")
                        )
                 ),

                 column(6,offset=0,
                        div(style = "font-size: 8px;padding: 0px 10px",      
                            selectInput(inputId = "size",
                                        label = "Tree Size",
                                        choices = c("All","Canopy","Subcanopy","Small"),
                                        selected = "All"),
                            tags$style(type = "text/css",
                                       #".select-dropdown-content {max-height: 4px; }")
                                       "#size {height: 4px; }")
                        )
                 )
               ),

               fluidRow(
                 tags$style(type="text/css", "#info {font-size: 10px;}"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("info")
               ),
               fluidRow(
                 tags$style(type="text/css", "#SPECinfo {font-size: 10px;}"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("SPECinfo")
               )
  ),

  mainPanel(width = 9,
            plotOutput(outputId = "nms", click = "plot_click",dblclick = "plot_dblclick")

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$scree <- renderPlot({

    par(mar = c(1.5,1.4,0.1,0.1), mgp = c(0.5,0.01,0), tcl = -0.1)
    plot(runif(99),runif(99),cex.axis=0.5,cex.lab=0.5,cex=0.75)

  },height = 95, width = 95) 

  output$nms <- renderPlot({

    plot(runif(99),runif(99))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get correctly what you mean you just need to modify the CSS of the shiny object. In this case the whole `sideBarPanel` has the html class `well`.

To demonstrate how to change it, I will use `tableHTML::make_css`. This function allows us to use a css object from within ui without loading a .css file. It will make demonstrating very easy:

If I add `tags$style(make_css(list('.well', 'border-width', '10px')))` within your `sideBarPanel` code, keeping everythin else the same:

```
 sidebarPanel(width = 3, 
              div(style = "font-size: 8px;", 
                  sliderInput(inputId = "groups", 
                              label = "No. of Groups",
                              value = 4, min = 2, max = 12)
              ),  
              #tags style expects a css file
              #which is what make_css creates
              #the first element of the list is the html class to modify
              #the second is the border-width
              #the third is the value of the width
              tags$style(make_css(list('.well', 'border-width', '10px'))),
              fluidRow(
               column(6,offset=0,
                      div(style = "height: 105px; padding: 0px 0px",  
                          plotOutput(outputId = "scree")
                      )
               )
```

You can see that the border changes to 10px:

[image]

This means that in order to reduce it, or remove it, you need to specify `0px` in the css:

```
 sidebarPanel(width = 3, 
              div(style = "font-size: 8px;", 
                  sliderInput(inputId = "groups", 
                              label = "No. of Groups",
                              value = 4, min = 2, max = 12)
              ),  
              tags$style(make_css(list('.well', 'border-width', '0px'))),
              fluidRow(
               column(6,offset=0,
                      div(style = "height: 105px; padding: 0px 0px",  
                          plotOutput(outputId = "scree")
                      )
               )
```

Which shows up like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Does it matter where the tags$style code goes?

Comment: You are very welcome! Usually no. Even if you put it between `titlePanel` and `sidebarPanel` it will still work. Or even right after `fluidPage`.

Comment: If you want to experiment easily with css in shiny, there is a nice tutorial [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/make_css.html) on how to use `make_css`.

Comment: Awesome. I'm still new to all of this (started shiny/css/html stuff 5 days ago), so these tutorials are what I really need! Many thanks!! :D

Comment: Great! Very happy to help :)

Comment: Very helpful thank you. Do you know if I don't want add space, but rather want add border around the sidebarpanel (in my case it is the header of shiny dashboard), where should I start?